# Related Questions vote count padding too small

Tags: bug, design

There seems to be a slight issue with the styling of the vote counters in the Related questions list, specifically when a question has a 3-digit vote count. The left and right padding does not match up with the others:

[image: related questions with no large minimum width]

Taking a look at the CSS, the 4-digit ones have the class `extra-large`, that defines a minimum width (32px):

```
.answer-votes.extra-large {
￼  font-size: 90%;
￼  padding-top: 4px;
￼  padding-bottom: 2px;
￼  min-width: 32px;
}
```

Whereas the 3-digit ones have the class `large` that does not:

```
.answer-votes.large {
￼  font-size: 90%;
￼  padding-top: 4px;
￼  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

And they end up with a minimum width of 20px from the `answer-votes` class, which is too narrow.

Adding a minimum width of 25px looks much better:

```
.answer-votes.large {
￼  font-size: 90%;
￼  padding-top: 4px;
￼  padding-bottom: 2px;
￼  min-width: 25px;
}
```

[image: related questions with large minimum width]

NB: This also applies to 3-digit vote counters using the default, unanswered style as opposed to the `answer-accepted` class.

#### Edit

Upon further inspection, this still doesn't work for 5-digit vote counters:

[image: related question with 5 digits]

It might be better to change the side padding here:

```
.show-votes .sidebar-related .answer-votes {
￼  background-color: #eee;
￼  color: #444;
￼  font-size: 90%;
￼  font-weight: normal;
￼  margin-right: 5px;
￼  padding: 2px 0 2px;
￼  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

to 3px, reduce the `answer-votes` minimum width to 14px to accomodate the change for 1-digit counts, and remove the minimum padding for the `large` and `extra-large` classes.

Comment: At 4+ digits they might want to use the "k" abbreviation.